Install ext-ftp extension using the official docker image
I am trying to install the php ftp extension without any luck. I am using the official docker PHP image. I am re-building the image with docker compose build --no-cache
I've also tried RUN docker-php-ext-enable ftp
FROM php:8.3-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install ftp

php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug

Update: I finally made it work with some adjustments to the dockerfile and running docker compose up again. :S
FROM php:8.3-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install ftp  && php -m | grep -i ftp \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions xdebug pdo_mysql mysqli @composer

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data  . /var/www/html

RUN chmod o+w /var/www/html -R

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]


Given the Docker image in question is actually or identical to
docker.io/library/php:8.3-fpm@sha256:28cfad4b9dfb7c378d861a757a9253e47cc8165b724f113160146fa8a41b48e1

and that you have tried docker-php-ext-enable ftp, double-check the diagnostic information it shows (at build time):
+ docker-php-ext-enable ftp

warning: ftp (ftp) is already loaded!


Furthermore, when grepping php -m output, the outcome with that base image may suggest that you've skipped the step to actually build the PHP ftp extension as it is automatically enabled:
+ php -m
+ grep -i ftp
ftp

or you're disabling the extension later on with your further configuration in the Docker composition.
In less words: Likely a configuration issue.

As you are building, I would suggest you enforce a rebuild of the image just to ensure to skip any cached build or container artefacts on your system.
You can either control that from the command line (docker compose command, cf. docker compose build)
or with the configuration (docker-compose.yml file, cf. Compose Build Specification).
Then verify the run and the outcome of RUN docker-php-ext-install ftp in the container build log.
Perhaps automatically by breaking if not immediately available:
FROM php:8.3-fpm

...

RUN docker-php-ext-install ftp && php -m | grep -Fx ftp

...

The build will break then if installing the ftp extension is not enabled.
If you would like to verify the log itself, it should start with:
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20230831
Zend Module Api No:      20230831
Zend Extension Api No:   420230831
...

And end with:
...

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.
+ strip --strip-all modules/ftp.so
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/
find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o -o -name \*.dep | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
rm -f libphp.la      modules/* libs/*
rm -f ext/opcache/jit/zend_jit_x86.c
rm -f ext/opcache/jit/zend_jit_arm64.c
rm -f ext/opcache/minilua

Finally, I would suggest first installing all PHP extensions, then changing the working directory for the order in the Dockerfile.
Now, after you have confirmed that the build actually has your wanted extension, verify any further PHP (extension) configuration by parenting configuration (like the Docker composition) does not void the build result by disabling the extension again.
Feel free to leave a comment and to share any more specifics apart from the Docker container name, its tag and the name of the PHP extension.
